# QTreeWidgetItem multiple selection using keyboard

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt5, qtreewidgetitem

I have a QTreeWidgetItem. I am able to set a multiple selection mode using *setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::MultipleSelection)*. In this case the user is able to select the items without using keyboard. When one clicks on an item it has become selected.

How can I make it selectable only using CTRL or Shift?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QAbstractItemView::ExtendedSelection` should provide the expected behaviour.

[Moved from comment to provide an acceptable answer.]

Comment: Thank you very much @Murphy

Comment: ExtendedSelection allows to select items while dragging the mouse over other items as well (except if the item is replaced by a widget, in that case it breaks the continuity), so it is not ONLY selectable using CTRL or shift keys.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need any mouse interaction with the items, you may try `item->setAttribute( Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents );`